When do expressions obtained by the use of normal coordinates actually hold?
I am reviewing some Riemannian geometry, and have gotten confused as to when expressions obtained using normal coordinates actually hold in generality. This may be mildly imprecise, so let me give an example or two.
Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian spin manifold, and $\nabla$ it's Levi-Civita connection. We get an induced Spin connection on the vector bundle of spinors $S$, and an exterior covariant derivative $D$.  Let $\Phi,\Psi\in \Gamma(S)$, then one can show somewhat easily via the use of Riemannian normal coordinates that if $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is a Dirac form then:
$$\langle D\Phi,\Psi\rangle_S-\langle \Phi,D\Psi\rangle_S=\star d\star \omega $$
for some $\omega\in \Omega^1(M,\mathbb C)$.  Since this is a global expression, it's very clear to me that ~we can~ use normal coordinates in this case to prove the result at all $p\in M$.
Now suppose $\eta=\eta_idx^i$ is a one form, and that $\nabla^2\eta=\eta_{ijk}dx^i\otimes dx^j \otimes dx^k$, then there is the result that:
$$\eta_{ijk}-\eta_{ikj}=R_{jki}^l\eta_l$$
where $R_{jki}^l$ is the Riemannian curvature.  I have seen this proved using normal coordinates, however, since this is a local expression, I don't see why it is valid to use normal coordinates in this case to prove such a statement.
If we can use normal coordinates to prove that statement, why does it not then follow that the Riemann tensor:
$$R_{ijkl}=g_{lp}\left(\partial_i\Gamma_{jk}^p-\partial_j\Gamma_{ik}^p+\Gamma_{jk}^q\Gamma_{iq}^p-\Gamma_{ik}^q\Gamma_{jq}^p\right)$$
can be rewritten as:
$$R_{ijkl}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_j\partial_lg_{ik}+\partial_{i}\partial_kg_{jl}-\partial_i\partial_lg_{jk}-\partial_j\partial_kg_{il}\right)$$
by appealing to normal coordinates?
Is there something fundamentally different about these two different local expressions?
